# Sci fi book, aliens on their planet are addicted to sugar

Tags: story-identification, books

This was read maybe early eighties in UK, a thin paperback. It could have been older.

What I remember:

Protagonist is newly arrived on this planet and is in a restaurant for Terrans, an alien orphan approaches him and begs for sugar so he gives one cube. Someone tells him that was way too much and he should have cut the cube up. The planet natives get high on the sucrose.

Later he gets into a gunfight but wins easily, it is explained he has came from Trippets (Tripps? Trippers?) Planet where duelling is commonplace. He is an experienced 'needle beamer', no explanation of this so it's possible this story was a sequel

There is some kind of uprising and the natives go on the warpath and lots of Terrans are killed before it all settles down. Some natives side with the Earthmen and (I think) wear like a striped poncho to differentiate themselves.

It is proven to be a rare mineral or plant extract that keeps the aliens calm, as population grows it gets rarer and thus a mini holocaust happens regularly.

I really can't remember if there was a description of the aliens

Note: On another site someone was discussing a book by Perry A. Chapdelaine titled 'Swampworld West' and I thought this was the same story as my question here.
However I've thought about it since and I'm not convinced that it was Swampworld West . (If anyone knows different then please enlighten me!)

There is a link to that site discussion provided by Valorum in the comments below.

Comment: [Either of these 2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/204496/58193)

Comment: Nope neither of them, it was maybe 1981 at the latest when I read it

Comment: That has some elements in common with a Keith Laumer Retief story, but he doesn't open a restaurant. He does use a needle beam in it and the aliens get high off of sugar water.

Comment: So not this; https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/573714/

Comment: Aha! @Valorum.... That's what inspired me to create this question. I thought about the book and don't think it was 'Swampworld West' that I was discussing, it feels like another story and I was mistaken in Chronicles

Comment: @zeta-band: I also immediately thought of Retief. Also, in the question, the protagonist doesn't OPEN a restaurant, he is merely IN a restaurant for Terrans.

Comment: Can anyone identify the Retief book please?

Comment: @DannyMcG It is Retief's War

Comment: People, having downloaded 'Retiefs War' I can confirm it is (with a load of memory errors from me) indeed the book I was looking for. I had mixed it up with The Darkness on Diamondia by Van Vogt and some other (unidentified!) novel. If someone would like to post it as an answer I'll accept. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this a potential answer, as suggested above, even though I have a few reservations.  The suggestion is [*Retief's War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2971) by Keith Laumer, the text of which is available on [Baen's website](http://baencd.freedoors.org/Books/Retief/0671318578__13.htm).  I've just re-read the story, and there aren't that many references to sugar (syrup actually, since it is imbibed) and it seems to be more of a social intoxicant (like alcohol) than a seriously addictive drug (like narcotics).  This is not to say there aren't syrup addicts, like we have alcoholics, just that addiction to syrup doesn't seem to be a significant concern.

In the opening scene the Quopp (native) bartender offers higher-quality syrup to Retief:

> "That's pretty good stuff," Gom-Goo said; he lowered his voice. "But for a real kick, you ought to try a shot of Hellrose—cut ten to one, of course. That'll put a charge on your plates."
>
> "I tried it once. Too sweet for a Terry. We like our sugar fermented."

Later on, Retief shares a drink with a couple of natives he's freed from a trap:

> "What about a drink, fellows?" Ozzl proposed. He took a hip flask from the flat pouch strapped to his lean flank, quaffed deeply, rose to his full three foot six, flexed his arms. "A new Quopp that'll make out of you," he announced and passed the bottle to Retief. He took a swallow; like all Quoppina liquors, it was thin, delicately flavored, resembling dilute honey. He passed the flask to Nopl, who drank, offered sulphurous sourballs which Retief declined.

Retief uses pure honey (stronger than normal syrups) as a distraction at a critical moment:

> Ikk and his troops spun on their wheels; one Voion scrabbled at a holster, brought up a gun as the jar arched through the air, smashed at his feet; a golden puddle spread across the rug in an aroma of pure Terran clover honey. There was a moment's stunned silence.
>
> "Sh—shoot him!" Ikk managed. The Voion with the gun dropped the weapon, dived for the fragrant syrup; an instant later, both interrogators were jackknifed over the honey, quivering in ecstasy, their drinking organs buried in nectar a thousand times stronger than the most potent Hellrose. Ikk alone still resisted, his antennae vibrating like struck gongs. He groped, brought up a gun, wavered, dithered, then with a thin cry dropped it and dived for the irresistible honey.

Other than a passing mention of the ambassador's private stock of aged Pepsi, which given the milieu may have been for his own consumption, that appears to be the direct mentions of consuming (sugary) syrups.

There is no scene in which a sugar cube is passed to an child, indeed most of the children - except notably the Rhoom - are portrayed as grubs.

There is no gunfight that Retief takes part in, he only uses a blaster in battle.  In keeping with most of the Retief stories, there is no mention of where he was previously posted except at the end where we see him turned out in his ceremonial reserve Battle Commander uniform.  A few Terrans are killed, but only a handful.  No colorful capes are worn by anyone.